# if $k>1$, Does $a+b =k(ax+by)$ have finitely many solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,k,x,y$ be non-zero integers, solve $a+b=k(ax+by)$. It's a rather simple problem, but I just want to make sure that I have got all the possible solutions.

Comment: There unknowns? And what integers are the problem?

Comment: @individ the unknowns are $x,y,k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are given fixed numbers $a$ and $b$, let's further assume that $a+b\ne0$ (otherwise it's an easy problem). Since $k\gcd(a,b)$ divides the right-hand side, a necessary condition for solutions to exist is that $k\gcd(a,b)\mid (a+b)$; equivalently, that $k$ divides $(a+b)/\gcd(a,b)$.

So now fix one of the finitely many integers $k$ dividing $(a+b)/\gcd(a,b)$. By [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity), there is a solution $(x_0,y_0)$ to $ax+by = \gcd(a,b)$; with that solution in hand, it's easy to construct infinitely many solutions to $ax+by = \gcd(a,b)$, namely $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0) + (tb/\gcd(a,b), -ta/\gcd(a,b))$. Now multiply any of these solutions by $(a+b)/k\gcd(a,b)$ to obtain solutions to $ax+by = (a+b)/k$.

Comment: That was my approach. Thank you Greg.

Comment: If you only want someone to confirm whether your approach is correct, it's better for you to include your approach in your OP. You're likely to get more/quicker responses that way - plus it's just more respectful for you to do as much work as you can, rather than to expect volunteer helpers to do more.

Comment: Point taken. if you review my post, you will see that i did mention the problem was simple. i just wanted to confirm other possible solutions besides $a+b=k(gcd(a,b))$ where $x,y$ are given by the Bezout's identity.I just wanted to confirm whether or not there was another approach given a different set of solutions.